# How do I 'count' while using 'where' in Laravel/Eloquent using Carbon

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to count the output I get using the following code:

### Blade.view

```
{{ $kentekens->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()) }}
```

This gives an output in String but instead I want to count the amount of matches it gets.
I tried the following without success:

```
{{ $kentekens->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->count()) }}

{{ $kentekens->count()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()) }}
```

### Controller

```
public function create() {
    $kentekens = Kenteken::latest()
        ->get();

    return view('layouts.dashboard', compact('kentekens'));
}
```

### Model

```
class Kenteken extends Model {
    protected $table = "kenteken";
}
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{ $kentekens->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->count() }}
```

Comment: Follow up question, what if I also want to count them where they need to have a specific first letter. I saw something like this but didn't work:


    *{{ $kentekens->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())-
    >where('kenteken', 'LIKE', 'B%')->count() }}*

Comment: @JesseyFransen you can use `like` only when querying the DB. When you working with a collection as you do here, you need to use `filter()` method with a closure.

Comment: I'm still a bit new. Could you give me a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

**QUESTION 1**

One solution is to add the two variables to the view from the controller :

**Controller**

```
public function create() {
    $kentekensQuery = Kenteken::latest()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today());

    return view('layouts.dashboard')
        ->with('kentekens', $kentekensQuery->get())
        ->with('kentekensCount', $kentekensQuery->count());
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $kentekens }}
{{ $kentekensCount }}
```

But this method make two sql request : the first to get the items, the second to count the items.

A better solution could be to return only the results of the first request as a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections), and call the [count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-count) method on that collection. The fact is that the get() method called on an Eloquent model query builder return a Collection. \o/

**Controller**

```
public function create() {
    $kentekens = Kenteken::latest()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today();

    return view('layouts.dashboard')
        ->with('kentekens', $kentekens->get());
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $kentekens }}
{{ $kentekens->count() }}
```

**QUESTION 2**

With the above first solution :

**Controller**

```
$kentekensQuery = Kenteken::latest()
     ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
     ->where('kenteken', 'LIKE', 'B%');
```

With the second solution, as @Alexei Mezenin said, you have to use a closure, a function run while iterating through each value on the collection with a function, here the [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter) function :

**View**

```
{{
    $kentekens->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return strpos($value, 'B') === 0;
    });
}}
```